# How to obtain stateful ssh shell session programmatically?

Tags: perl, ssh, openssh

I am working on an application that needs to send commands to remote servers. Sending commands is easy enough with the plethora of SSH client libraries.

However, I would like shell state (i.e. current working directory, environment variables, etc) preserved between each command. All client libraries that I have seen do not do this. For example, the following is an example of code that does **not** do what I want:

```
use Net::SSH::Perl;
my $server = Net::SSH::Perl->new($host);
$server->login($user, $pass);

$server->cmd('cd /var');
$server->cmd('pwd');      # I _would like_ this to output /var
```

There will be other tasks performed between sending commands, so combining the commands like `$server->cmd('cd /var; pwd')` is not acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

[Net::SSH::Expect](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aSSH%3a%3aExpect) does what you want, though the "Expect" way is not completely reliable as it will be parsing the output of your commands and trying to detect when the shell prompt appears again.

Comment: It's just fine so long as you only run commands that you know how to parse the output of.

Comment: @Joshua: well, I discovered later that Net::SSH::Expect does not use any logic to find out when the command is done. It just has a (customizable) timeout and assumes that the command is done when the timeout is over. Completely unreliable!

Comment: EWWW. You might do well then to write the darn thing in expect directly then.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are doing exactly, but you could just start one SSH session. If you really can't do this, maybe you can just use absolute paths for everything.